# Google tag manager does not register click event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up a click event for a certain button in GA4 Analytics in GTM, but the event does not fire in the preview.

The button has a specific ID. I can see the [ID in the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcEMT.png), I can see that [the gtm.element contains the ID in the API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUSSE.png), but the [debug information shows that the Click ID does not match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBoUC.png).

I've tested with my front-end developers that the event click events are propagated through the DOM. On a simple image where I've set up the click event in the same way the click event is properly registered.

Any insight in how to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshots. Looks like GTM detect the click is fired on the `<span>` inside the button you want.

For this kind of case. I would suggest to use `click element` as your trigger.

[image]

Here is the selector

```
button#ga_welcome_start_print_job, button#ga_welcome_start_print_job *
```

This means we want to track the click for the button and all the element inside it.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; wrap text in an attribute that has id property. Make a custom variable in GTM, of type 'Auto Event Variable' -> Variable Type = Element ID. Then assign to tag.

I had a similar situation. I was using React MUI's Button and I noticed that the id attribute wasn't actually being assigned to GA4's elementId. My guess is the id attribute wasn't 'bubbling' up or it was being processed somehow in MUI which conflicts with GA4. Anyways, I literally just started using analytics, so here's what I did to get it working.

I had a MUI button with the following setup

```
    <Button
      id='location-filter-tag' 
      className='reco-filter-button'
      variant={searchState === 'cumulative' ? "contained" : "text"}
      size="small"
      onClick={() => {
        setQueryType('cumulative');
      }}
    > 
    <h6 className="some-class"> 
       Location 
    </h6> 
    </Button>
```

Checking the the push event `gtm.click` below, you can see the  `id='location-filter-tag'`  is concatenated into one big string. under `gtm.element`.

[image]

At the time, the `gtm.elementId` was an empty string (image is of working instance)

I tried to hook into `gtm.element` and trigger the tag using contains = location-filter-tag but that didn't work. **So I moved the id property to the child attribute to get it to register with GA4's gtm.elementId**

```
      <h6 
        id='location-filter-tag' 
        className="text-overflow reco-filter-text"
      >
```

Then in google tag manager, I setup a variable like so:

[image]

Then I assigned it as a trigger. This is my location trigger

[image]

hope that helps.